# Get 10+ level category hierarchy relationship

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, product, hierarchy

Needs to get the category hierarchy from top to bottom
Which mean we have c1 code from c1 needs to get c1-->c2-->c3-->c4--> etc,.
I have an 'category' object it stores all the category names and codes and having another object 'parent category' which store the hierarchy(relation) of the each category records

Please check the above image for your references
Eg: In category object :

| Name | code | id(18digit) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 111XXXX |
| A1 | 11 | 112XXXX |
| A2 | 12 | 113XXXX |
| A3 | 13 | 114XXXX |
| A11 | 111 | 115XXXX |
| A12 | 112 | 116XXXX |
| B | 21 | 117XXXX |
| B1 | 22 | 118XXXX |

Eg : In parent category object Storing the relationship of category
Fields :

| Label | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| ParentCatId | Lookup(Category__c) |
| childCatId | Lookup(Category__c) |

Eg:

| ParentCatId | childCatId |
| --- | --- |
| Null | A |
| A | A1 |
| A1 | A2 |
| A2 | A3 |
| A | A11 |
| A11 | A12 |
| Null | B |
| B | B1 |

The above is the object architecture and sample data for your understanding.

Now currently i am having the record A code(first level code) 10.

1. 10 -> 11 --> 12-->13
2. 10 --> 111 --> 112

How can i find using 1) and 2)
with the top level category code using apex (without breaking the governor limits in salesforce). Any one can help me on this to achieve using apex.

Please check the below code

```
public CategoryHelperClass() //Constructor
{
    //pass first category code 
    getCategoryProducts(catCode);
}

public static void getCategoryProducts(List<String> catCode){ //Method
    System.debug('catCode::'+catCode);
    catProdWrapper catProd=new catProdWrapper(); //Wrapper Initialization
    Map<String, List<String>> getcatProd=new Map<String, List<String>>();
    //List<Parent_Category__c> categoryList=new List<Parent_Category__c>();
    List<String> childCatCodes=new List<String>();
    List<String> lastLevelCat=new List<String>();
    List<String> removeList=new List<String>();
    Boolean flag=true;
    //Query to check/get the child category
     
    if(!catCode.isEmpty()){
        for(Parent_Category__c parentCar : [Select Child_Category_ID__r.Id, Child_Category_ID__r.Name, Child_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c,
                                            Parent_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c from Parent_Category__c 
                                            Where Parent_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c IN:catCode]){
                                                System.debug('parentCar::'+parentCar);  
                                                System.debug(':::::++++'+parentCar.Child_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c);
                                                System.debug(':::::++++'+parentCar.Child_Category_ID__r.Name);
                                                if(parentCar != null){
                                                    childCatCodes.add(parentCar.Child_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c);
                                                    removeList.add(parentCar.Parent_Category_ID__r.Category_Id__c);
                                                }else{
                                                    //
                                                }
                                            }
    }
    System.debug('childCatCodes::'+childCatCodes);
    System.debug('removeList::'+removeList);
   
    
    if(childCatCodes.size() > 0){
        getCategoryProducts(childCatCodes);
    }
}
```

I needs to store all the child category in a variable . When i get the level2 category again i cant able to store the level3 child values in the same variable because the method invoking again. how to achieve this can some one help me on this ? Check the below obj structure for your reference in the image.
i needs to get the all the last level categories for one parent category.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @DavidCheng, thanks
I have add the code where i was stucked